# Spring Batch MongoDB to XML example

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

I am looking to developed the `Spring batch MongoDB to XML` example. I search a lot on google, but I found all sample examples other way around i.e, `XML to MongoDB`. Could anyone please provide link / blog etc to starts with ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to read data from MongoDB and write them to a XML file?

Comment: Nghia - Yes, read from mongodb and write to XML or CSV

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.html

Comment: Luca - Thnx for this link. But would be great if somehow I get sort of sample code to start with.

Comment: Loca - Could you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500945/cannot-convert-value-of-type-org-springframework-batch-item-xml-staxeventitemwr

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to do the following :

1) You need to use `MongoItemReader` API to read the collection from the mongodb.

2) If you want to write `mongodb collection` data in to XML file, then you can use `StaxEventItemWriter`

3) You need to use `Jaxb2Marshaller` to Marshall the data into the XML format.

**Please refer the following links which I developed the code.**

- [Spring Batch - MongoDB to XML - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A type to convert the input into is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503096/spring-batch-mongodb-to-xml-caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-a-ty)
- [Spring Batch - MongoDB to XML - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A type to convert the input into is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503096/spring-batch-mongodb-to-xml-caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-a-ty)